# SimpleImage not found tmp file

Tags: php

I want to create a form that saves an image sent via the form to an image folder on the server. I made a script to do this thanks to the simpleImage class, the file registers well when I do not use the class but with simpleImage I have a "File not found C: / Wamp64 / tmp /. ... "

Here is the script in question

```
    function Image($folder, $tailleMax= 4){
  $listMime = array(
    ".jpeg" => "image/jpeg",
    ".jpg" => "image/jpg",
    ".gif" => "image/gif",
    ".png" => "image/png"
  );
  $listExtension = array_flip($listMime);
  $error = "max $tailleMax Mo.";
  $error .= "<br />
  Extensions : ".implode(",", $listeExtension).".";
  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    if(empty($_FILES)){
      $retour = "Max $tailleMax.";
    }
    else{
      $fileErreur = $_FILES["file"]["error"];
      $error = "error";
    }
    $tmpFile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $typeMime = finfo_file($finfo, $tmpFile);
    finfo_close($finfo);

    if(!in_array($typeMime, $listMime)){
      $error = "Extension";
    }
    else{
      $extension = array_search($typeMime, $listMime);
      if(!is_dir($folder)){
        mkdir($folder);
      }
      $fileExist = glob($folder."/*");
      foreach ($fileExist as $file) {
        unlink($file);
      }
      if(!move_uploaded_file($tmpFile, $file."/-"."picture".$extension)){
        $error = "Error";
      }
      else{
        $error = "ok";
      }
/////////The script works so far`enter code here`
      $picture = new \claviska\SimpleImage();
      try{
        $picture->fromFile($tmpFile);
        if (isset($picture->getExif()["Orientation"])){
          $picture->autoOrient();
        }

        $picture->bestFit(800, 600)->toFile($folder."/-picture-large".$extension, $typeMime, 70);
        $picture->thumbnail(150, 150)->toFile($folder."/-picture-min".$extension, $typeMime, 70);
        $error = "OK";
      }
      catch(Exception $err){
        $error = $err->getMessage();
      }//fermeture catch
    }
  }
  return $error;
}
```

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` moves the file from the tmp folder and deletes it from the tmp folder. Load your image from the place you put the uploaded file before you do the thumbnail processing and all will be well. EG `$picture->fromFile($file."/-"."picture".$extension);`

Comment: Yes it's work Thank you